# Help understanding `find` syntax on Solaris

Tags: find, solaris

Consider the following files:

```
$ find findtest                     
findtest
findtest/test1
findtest/test1/start.ksh
findtest/test2
findtest/test2/start.ksh
findtest/test3
findtest/test3/start.ksh
findtest/test4
findtest/test4/start.ksh
```

My question is about the use of `{}` in the `-exec` call. It works as I would expect it when designating the result file:

```
$ find findtest -name test[1-4] -exec ls -d {} \;           
findtest/test1
findtest/test2
findtest/test3
findtest/test4
```

However it doesn't seem to be expanded when used in a path:

```
$ find findtest -name test[1-4] -exec md5sum {}/start.ksh \;     
md5sum: {}/start.ksh: No such file or directory
md5sum: {}/start.ksh: No such file or directory
md5sum: {}/start.ksh: No such file or directory
md5sum: {}/start.ksh: No such file or directory
```

How can I use `find -type d -exec` to access lower hierarchy files?
I know I can use a `for` loop like this, but I am curious to know if it can be done in one `find` call:

```
$ for f in $(find findtest -name test[1-4]); do md5sum "$f"/start.ksh; done
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  findtest/test1/start.ksh
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  findtest/test2/start.ksh
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  findtest/test3/start.ksh
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  findtest/test4/start.ksh
```

Comment: I've tested your second example (`md5sum` with `find`), and it seems to work on Linux. Thus it seems to be a Solaris flavor.

Comment: That wouldn't be the first time something like that happens. Solaris is a strange beast. I used to get irritated at first, but I'm finding out these shortecomings usually have a reason.

Comment: It's still better to pass it via xargs, it would be much faster.

Comment: @Jiri Not sure it would be measurable in that case. Anyway, find doesn't need xargs as -exec has the same feature built in.

Comment: -exec is done for each findings, xargs works on multiple foundings...

Comment: @Jiri Not necessarily. Have a look at the second suggestion in my reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [POSIX standard for the find command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/find.html) only mandates an isolated {} to be replaced by the filename, and only the first one. Using `{}/start.ksh` lead to unspecified behavior.

> An argument containing only the two characters "{}" shall be replaced
>   by the set of aggregated pathnames, with each pathname passed as a
>   separate argument to the invoked utility in the same order that it was
>   aggregated. The size of any set of two or more pathnames shall be
>   limited such that execution of the utility does not cause the system's
>   {ARG_MAX} limit to be exceeded. If more than one argument containing
>   only the two characters "{}" is present, the behavior is unspecified.
>
> If a utility_name or argument string contains the two characters "{}",
>   but not just the two characters "{}", it is implementation-defined
>   whether find replaces those two characters or uses the string without
>   change.

One way to do what you want with Solaris find would be that command:

```
find findtest -name "test[1-4]" -exec sh -c 'md5sum $1/start.ksh' foo {} \;
```

A faster way would be:

```
find findtest -name "test[1-4]" -exec sh -c 'for i; do md5sum "$i/start.ksh"; done' foo {} +
```

Comment: Thanks for a spot on answer. I would be very interested to know why your second command is faster than the first? Is it `ksh` specific or is it the same on all shells?

Comment: @rahmu It is faster because it concatenates all of the arguments and runs them in a single shell session, instead of creating a new shell session for each argument.

Comment: @rahmu That's it. The `+` terminator is equivalent but simpler than using xargs. There is nothing ksh specific in the commands I suggested, they would run with the legacy /bin/sh, bash or ksh.

Comment: Oh yes. I got confused by `for i;`.  This is what I suspected to be shell specific. To make sure I got it right, is this just an implicit way of writing `for i in $*`?

Comment: It is almost equivalent. More precisely, it an implicit way of writing `for i in "$@"`

Answer (score 0):

1. Actually your shell is expanding `test[1-4]` before it invokes `find`. You need to escape it with `'…'`
2. `{}` gets treated as pattern only when it's being a separate token

`-exec` itself is usually costy and recommended to be used either with trailing `+`, or avoided in favor of feeding `xargs`.

> I know I can use a for loop like this, but I am curious to know if it can be done in one find call:

`find findtest -name 'test[1-4]' -print0 | xargs -0I{} -- md5sum '{}/start.ksh'` — runs `md5sum` efficiently — with all file names given at once.

Comment: This won't work on Solaris. Your find and xargs commands are non standard compliant by using Gnuisms.

Comment: @jlliagre, ORLY? How does it works fine for me on `SunOS solaris 5.11 11.0 i86pc i386 i86pc`, then?

Comment: It indeed works on Solaris 11 because you have /usr/gnu/bin first in your PATH. rahmu is very likely using Solaris 10 or older that do not bundle gnu find and xargs. Otherwise `find findtest -name test[1-4] -exec md5sum {}/start.ksh \;` would have work in the first place.

Comment: @jlliagre, `PATH` has only `/usr/bin:/usr/sbin`. Any further guesses?

Comment: Granted. The `find ... -print0` and `xargs -0`  Gnuisms have been integrated in Solaris 11 standard commands to improve user familiarity. I should rephrase my comment, "This won't work on Solaris 10 or older, which is what rahmu is using".

Comment: By the way, about your first comment, the shell is only expanding `test[1-4]` if there is a match in the current directory. Otherwise, the argument is left as is which is the case with rahmu. Quoting is nevertheless a good advice.

Comment: @jlliagre, well, too bad for Solaris' users — FreeBSD have had this since 1995. :)

Comment: No problem for Solaris users who actually had a reliable solution since 1992 (first implemented by David Korn in 1988 on SVR4.0).  http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/find/dgk-20010326.html